# Probability density vs probability in Bayesian statistics

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I have started learning Bayesian statistics recently, but I am confused about probability densities and probability. I do know they are different, and I can usually identify both, but in one problem, I am confused if I am calculating a probability density or probability.

Here is the description:

I have a variable,

$m \sim N(\frac{a+b}2, 1)$

The prior distribution for $a$ and $b$ are as follows- both $a$ and $b$ are uniformly distributed over $[-1,1]$.

I wanted to calculate,

$P(0 \leq b \leq 1 |0 \leq a \leq 1, m=0)$.

If I calculate this, will I have a probability density or probability? If it is a probability density, can its value exceed 1?

Especially, if I find that the value of the expression is greater than $0.5$, does that mean that given the conditions, the probability of getting a positive $b$ is greater than $0.5$? And that the probability of $b$ being less than $0$ is less than $0.5$?

Answer (score 3):

> The distinction between probability density and probability of an
>   event has little to relate with Bayesian statistics.

Given a random variable $X$, with distribution $P^X$, this distribution can be characterised by the definition of $P^X(A)$ for all measurable sets $A$, or equivalently by the definition of a density $p^X$ wrt a measure $\text{d}\mu$ if the distribution is absolutely continuous wrt this measure, the connection being that
$$P^X(A) = \int_A p^X(x)\text{d}\mu(x)$$
For instance, if $\text{d}\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $P^X$ the Uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$, 
$$P^X([0,1])=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}$$
When dealing with *conditional distributions*, things are pretty much the same, namely that given $m=0$ and $0\le a\le 1$, $b$ is a random variable with a probability distribution denoted by e.g. $$P^b(\cdot|0\le a\le 1,m=0)$$ which is associated with a probability coverage of all measurable sets $A$ in $[-1,1]$,
$$P^b(A|0\le a\le 1,m=0)$$and which enjoys a probability density $$p^b(\cdot|0\le a\le 1,m=0)$$ wrt the Lebesgue (uniform) measure on $[-1,1]$, such that
$$P^b(A|0\le a\le 1,m=0)=\int_A p^b(x|0\le a\le 1,m=0)\text{d}x$$The only part where Bayes has a say is in defining this *conditional distribution*, since Bayes' theorem states that
$$P^b(A|0\le a\le 1,m=0)=\frac{P^b(A,0\le a\le 1|m=0)}{P^b(0\le a\le 1|m=0)}$$

Comment: This is all correct (+1), but it is pitched at a level that is miles beyond someone who is just starting to learn probability (unless that person has come across with a maths degree but somehow has never seen probability before).

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with continuous random variables, one way that you can tell the difference between probability and probability density is that the former applies to *events* involving random variables, whereas the latter applies to *individual values* of continuous random variables.  Another way to tell is that we usually denote probabilties using an upper-case symbol like $\mathbb{P}$, $\text{P}$, $\text{Pr}$ or $P$, whereas we usually denote densities using a lower-case symbol like $f$ or $p$.

Now, if you look at your $P$ statement, you will see firstly that it is an upper-case symbol.  But more importantly, you will notice that the variable of interest is stipulated to fall within a particular range, rather than being at an individual value.  This gives you the *event* $\{ 0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1 \}$ so you are looking at the conditional *probability* of that event.  This conditional probability can be computed from the underlying densities as:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1 | 0 \leqslant a \leqslant 1, m=0)
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(0 \leqslant b \leqslant 1, 0 \leqslant a \leqslant 1| m=0)}{\mathbb{P}(0 \leqslant a \leqslant 1| m=0)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 p(a, b|m=0) \ da \ db}{\int_0^1 p(a|m=0) \ da}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

Since this is a probability, its value must be between zero and one.  (And yes, a probability density value can exceed one.)  Also, note that the distinction between probability and probability density is not specific to Bayesian statistics --- it occurs within probability theory, and arises in all statistical methodologies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!